# Solutions and Office.com

Tags: sandbox-solution, solution-package

Does anyone know when/how office.com will integrate with sandbox solutions

Google

http://www.google.com.au/search?q=sharepoint+solution+office.com&rls=com.microsoft:en-au&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&redir_esc=&ei=J98zTcaBAZG2vQOlusilCw

Only returns the placeholder page

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-sharepoint-solutions-on-office-com-HA101842207.aspx

Is there any other information around?

Comment: Made CW. Due to open ended nature of Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandbox solutions are not going to be on the store.
Its all about the Apps now.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SharePoint Online: An Overview for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg317460.aspx) and this [Blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vedant/archive/2010/11/03/office-365-part-4-sharepoint-online.aspx). No idea about the release date.

Answer (score 0):

The ribbon button is present because the feature was pulled (from Office.com) too late into the release cycle.  Solutions never have, nor will ever be at Office.com.